# Load values from MySQL DB to specific column in datagrid view

Tags: c#, mysql, database, winforms, datagrid

I want to extract data from a DB. I need to display only the first three columns (0,1,2) instead of all. How could I do that?

```
>     string selectQuery = "select command line goes here where.... offerMadeBy='"+cbox1.Text.ToString()+"';";
>                 MySqlConnection sqlCOnnect = new MySqlConnection(RootDBConnection.myConnection);
>                 MySqlCommand sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery,sqlCOnnect);
>                 MySqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter;
>                 try {
>                     sqlAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
>                     sqlAdapter.SelectCommand = sqlCmd;
>     
>                     DataTable dbset = new DataTable();
>                     sqlAdapter.Fill(dbset);
>                     BindingSource bindSource = new BindingSource();
>     
>                     _dataGridView.DataSource = null;
>                     bindSource.DataSource = dbset;
>                     _dataGridView.DataSource = bindSource;
>                     sqlAdapter.Update(dbset);
>     
>     
>                     if (sqlCOnnect.State == ConnectionState.Open) {
>                         sqlCOnnect.Close();
>                     }
>                 }catch(MySqlException ex){
>                     MessageBox.Show("Can't load data from DB.\nReason:"+ex.Message);
>                 }
```

Comment: Can't you just only select the columns you need in your sql (`selectQuery`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just select the fields you want from your Database. Moreover you must open your connection to SQL and lastly use parameters, e.g:

```
string selectQuery = "select field1,field2,field3 from mytable where offerMadeBy=@param";
MySqlConnection sqlCOnnect = new MySqlConnection(RootDBConnection.myConnection);
MySqlCommand sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery,sqlCOnnect);
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", cbox1.Text.ToString());
try { 
       sqlCOnnect.Open()
       using (sqlCOnnect)
       {
        ....
       }
      }
```

Comment: well, for the tip.That was obvious like get values from DB to Combobox. Ok, can you explain why i should writ like that "@" and Parameters.AddWIthValue? This is just prevents SQL Injections?

Comment: Yes the most important benefit is injection prevention, but moreover using aprameters optimizes the query execution from c# part